# Finding $c$ such that $\ln\cosh x \approx \sqrt{c^2+x^2}-c$

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, systems-of-equations, approximation, maxima-minima

The real function $$f(x) =  \ln\cosh x$$ loosely resembles the shape of a hyperbola

$$h_c(x) = \sqrt{c^2+x^2} - c$$

and my question is **what's the best $c$ in terms of the maximum norm**, i.e.
$$
\text{Let } c \text{ be such that } \|f-h_c\|_{\max} \stackrel!=\min \tag 1
$$
For large $|x|$ we have that $f(x)\approx|x|-\ln2$ so that $c=\ln 2$ is a choice with
$$
\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}(f(x) - h_{\ln2}(x)) = 0
$$
However it's $h_{\ln2}(x)\geqslant f(x)$ (with equality for $x=0$) so that $c=\ln2$ is not optimal with respect to $(1)$: A better hyperbola would trade positive error against negative error equally so that

$$\sup (f-h_c) = -\inf(f-h_c)$$

presumably with $c\in[\ln 2, 1]$ somewhere $c\approx 0.8$. So what's the best $c$? One idea it to use $c>\ln2$ so that

$$
\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}(f(x) - h_c(x)) = c-\ln2=\delta > 0
$$
and find $x_0$ such that

$$-\delta = \inf (f-h_c) = f(x_0)-h_c(x_0)$$
so that $x_0$ is a local minimum of $f-h_c$. For the local minimum, taking derivative and determine $x_0$ and $c$ such that:

$$f'(x_0)-h'_c(x_0) = \tanh x_0 - \frac{x_0}{\sqrt{c^2+x_0^2}} \stackrel!= 0 \tag 2$$
and simultaneously
$$
f(x_0)-h_c(x_0) = \ln\cosh x -\sqrt{c^2+x_0^2}+c\stackrel!= \ln2 -c \tag 3
$$
so it's a system of two equations for two variables $c$ and $x_0\neq0$ where $x_0$ is only determined up to sign. But I don't know how to preceed from here.

---

**Addendum:**  The current choice of $h_c$ is such that $h_c(0) = 0$.  As an extension of the problem, this requirement could be dropped so that the available space becomes a 2-parameter family of functions $h_{c,d}(x)=\sqrt{c^2+x^2}-d$.

---

**Addendum 2:** To solve the system (2)+(3): Using (2), express $c$ in terms of $x$:

$$\sqrt{c^2+x^2}=\frac x{\tanh x}\quad\text{ and }\quad
c = |x|\sqrt{\frac{1}{\tanh^2 x}-1} \tag 4$$
Drop these into (3) to eliminate $c$ and to determine $x$:

$$\ln\cosh x-\frac{x}{\tanh x}+2|x|\sqrt{\frac{1}{\tanh^2 x}-1}-\ln 2 \stackrel!= 0 \tag 5$$

Numerical (Newton-Raphson) approximation of (5) yields $|x|\approx1.317$, which can be plugged back into (4) to get $c$:

$$c\approx0.7603459963 \quad\text{ and }\quad \|f-h_c\|_\max\approx 0.0671$$
where the original distance was $\|f-h_{\ln 2}\|_\max\approx 0.10387$, so that there is an improvement.

---

**Addendum 3:** Finding a more general hyperbola $h(x)=\sqrt{c^2+x^2}-d$ as of Addendum 1 is no more complicated than the computation above, so here it is: In order to establish an [equi-oscillation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equioscillation_theorem) property, make the ansatz

$$\begin{align}
f(0) - h(0) &= d-c \stackrel!= \delta \tag{6.1}\\
f(\infty) - h(\infty) &= d-\ln2 \stackrel!= \delta \tag{6.2}\\
f(x_0) - h(x_0) &\stackrel!= -\delta \tag{6.3}\\
\end{align}$$
From (6.1) and (6.2) it follows that $c=\ln 2\approx0.69315$. Then differentiate (6.3) to find $x_0$ as a local extremum. The derivative of (6.3) is (2), but this time for an already known $c=\ln 2$.  Solving it yields $x\approx1.5366$ and then combine (6.3) with (6.1) to find $d$ as

$$d = \frac12\big(c-f(x)+\sqrt{c^2+x^2}\big)$$
Plugging in the values yields

$$d\approx 0.74508129\quad\text{ and }\quad
 \|f-h_{c,d}\|_\max \approx 0.052$$
so this proximal hyperbola with its distance of 0.052 from $f$ is again closer than the 0.067 from Addendum 2.

Comment: @njuffa: Thanks for the effort.  What ashtonishes me is that you got a solution that's even closer to the curve than what I got via equi-oscillation (0.0511 instead of by 0.052).

Comment: @njuffa: So its actually a better solution and not an artifact of Monte Carlo?

Comment: Thank you for all your analysis and research!

Comment: Verify that $(x_0, c) = (\operatorname {arccosh} 2, \operatorname {arccosh}(2)/\sqrt 3)$ solves (2) and (3).

Answer (score 2):

*This is not an answer.*

**Numerical results**

Consider the norm
$$\Phi(c,k)=\int_0^{10^k} \Big[\sqrt{c^2 +x^2}-c -\log (\cosh (x))\Big]^2\,dx$$ and minimize it with respect to $c$ for a given $k$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k & \Phi_{\text{min}} & c_{\text{opt}} \\ 
 1 & 0.01092 & 0.753021 \\
 2 & 0.02975 & 0.703006 \\
 3 & 0.03715 & 0.694634 \\
 4 & 0.03898 & 0.693350 \\
 5 & 0.03933 & 0.693173
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Trying to solve $(2)$**

$$\tanh (x)-\frac{x}{\sqrt{c^2+x^2}}=0$$
For large $x$, we have $$\tanh(x) = 1 - 2 e^{-2x} + o(e^{-2x})$$ So, we have
$$e^{-2x} \sim \frac{\sqrt{c^2+x^2}-x}{2 \sqrt{c^2+x^2}}=\frac{c^2}{4 x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right)\implies x \sim -W\left(-\frac{c}{2}\right)$$ which would require $c \leq \frac 2e$ but this does not allow to find a solution for $(3)$.

So, we would need to use
$$\tanh(x) = 1 - 2 e^{-2x}+ 2 e^{-4x}+ o(e^{-6x})$$ and solve for $X=e^{-2x}$ the equation
$$1-2X+2X^2 =\frac{c^2}{4 x^2}$$

Comment: For the numerical result, I think that $c_\text{opt}\to\ln2$ as $k$ increases because otherwise, the area between $\ln\cosh$ and the hyperbola would tend to infinity as $k\to\infty$?

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts. The solution of $(2)=0$ and $(3)=0$ is $x=0$ and $c=\log(2)$

Comment: The solution $x=0$ minimizes the distance which will be 0 for $x=0$ because the graphs touch there.  So only solutions $x_0\neq 0$ are of interest and that maximize the distance (and $c$ such that the maximum gets minimal). Plotting graphs, there is indication that there's a proximum at around $c=0.8$ so maybe my derivations / assumptions for (2) and (3) are wrong?

Comment: I had miscalculated the derivative with a superflouos factor of 2 in the numerator.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts. I wrote it in a comment four hours ago. Didn't you see it ? Cheers :-)